# Recent Posts widget without Title

Tags: widgets, recent-posts

I want to add "Recent Posts" widget in a sidebar without a title but every time I add it, it shows "Recent Posts" text as title. How do I have it without title? I don't want to use any plugin for this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will set the title to an empty string if it is set to `Recent Posts` (Which as you noted, is what the Recent Posts widget will set the title to if it is empty):

```
add_filter( 'widget_title', 'wpse_widget_title', 10, 3 );
function wpse_widget_title( $title, $instance, $id_base ) {
    if ( 'recent-posts' === $id_base && __( 'Recent Posts', 'text_domain' ) === $title ) {
        $title = '';    
    }

    return $title;
}
```

Another workaround is to set the title to the HTML entity for a space, `&nbsp;` in the widget editor.

Answer (score 2):

Go to 'Appearance -> Customize -> Additional CSS' and add:

```
.widget_recent_entries>h3 {
    display: none;
}
```

Click on 'Save&Publish'. Exit customizer.